# Starting application in another Android smartphone over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

As the title suggests, I am developing an app, which can connect and pair with another Android phone. I can successfully scan, connect, pair and transmit String data over bluetooth. I tested by sending String data and received it in another android smartphone and showed it in the toast.

**The actual scenario**

This application will be installed in both android phones. Once another android phone scans and connect to the phone over bluetooth, then I want to launch this app. I know we can accomplish this using BroadcastReceiver. But how can I implement this in terms of Bluetooth connection. Any code snippet or idea or suggestions are welcomed..

Comment: "I want to launch this app"? You mean the app which receives BT commands  or some other app?

Comment: Yes, the app which received BT commands..

Comment: See my Answer will that help u?

Answer (score 0):

After you get the BT msg,Hope you followed this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) ,Here after "// Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity"
Send a broadcast to start your app.

Loop with the list of apps installed and know which app to be launched and use the below to launch a app.

```
public String getPreInstalledPocPkgName(){
        String pkgName = null;
        try {
            List<PackageInfo> pkgInfoList = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

            for(PackageInfo pkgInfo:pkgInfoList){

                pkgName = pkgInfo.packageName;

                if(pkgName==null || pkgName.equals("")){
                    continue;
                }
                for(String name:pttPkgList){
                    if(pkgName.equals(name)){
                        Log.d(TAG, "------------ app with package name ["+pkgName+"] already installed----------");
                        return pkgName;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "-------Error! while fetching previously installed  app------", e);
            clearConfigFromSharedPath();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "------------No previously installed  app----------");
        return null;
    } 
}



   String pttAppPkgName = getPreInstalledPocPkgName();
       Or 
         pttAppPkgName = your app package.
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pttAppPkgName);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I know how to retrieve the applications those are on device, but how can I launch it using BroadcastReceiver class, that receives the message in onReceive method? Morevoer, this should be done also when the app is in background state. I am really confused..

Comment: Send a BT msg saying "startAPP",once you receive it do the last part of my code which will launch your app.